# In pagination, change link for page 1 to homepage

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

I have a problem, when I am on page 2 or on any other page and I want to return to the index, the url that offers me the pagination on page 1 is the following (https://www.url.com/page/1) and I would like it to be as it usually is (https://www.url.com)

El código que tengo en el fuctions.php es el siguiente:

```
function mt_paginacion($tipo=1,$class=NULL,$qc=NULL){

global $wp_query,$paged;

if($qc==''){$total=$wp_query->max_num_pages;}else{$total=$qc;}

if($tipo==1){

$paginacion=paginate_links( array(

    'base' => str_replace(999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link(999999999) ) ),

    'format' => '?paged=%#%',

    'current' => max( 1, $paged ),

    'total' => $total,

    'mid_size' => 3,

    'prev_next' => true

) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple `str_replace( '/page/1/', '/', $string )` on the results generated by `paginate_links()` to get rid of `/page/1/` which appears on the first page link as well as the Prev link (when it points to the first page).

Here's a full (tested) example:

```
/**
 * Numeric pagination via WP core function paginate_links().
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links
 *
 * @param array $srgs
 *
 * @return string HTML for numneric pagination
 */
function wpse_pagination( $args = array() ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 ) {
        return;
    }

    $pagination_args = array(
        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
        'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
        'show_all'     => false,
        'type'         => 'array',
        'end_size'     => 2,
        'mid_size'     => 3,
        'prev_next'    => true,
        'prev_text'    => __( '&laquo; Prev', 'wpse' ),
        'next_text'    => __( 'Next &raquo;', 'wpse' ),
        'add_args'     => false,
        'add_fragment' => '',

        // Custom arguments not part of WP core:
        'show_page_position' => false, // Optionally allows the "Page X of XX" HTML to be displayed.
    );

    $pagination = paginate_links( array_merge( $pagination_args, $args ) );

    // Remove /page/1/ from links.
    $pagination = array_map(
        function( $string ) {
            return str_replace( '/page/1/', '/', $string );
        },
        $pagination
    );

    return implode( '', $pagination );
}
```

**Usage:**

```
echo wpse_pagination();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new function, this simple solution is for you: [How to Remove page/1/ from WordPress Pagination](https://weusewp.com/tutorial/pagination-remove-page-1/)